# Network Tapping cat3750/3850

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, tap

I work with tapagg solutions as an NDR engineer. Upgrading my lab for various reasons. Right now I SPAN with an old cat2960 into my packet system. I need to bump up to gig span and would like some 10G sfp options for my hypervisor.
Will I be able to do this with a 3850/3750 with LANbase licensing?
I don't need the routing, just span. I think I will be able to, but I can't find a clear answer in ciscos docs for those models. My 2960s span on LANbase.
If I didn't also need more ports at the same time, I'd get a tap and kick cisco to the curb.

Comment: The 3750 is EoL for years. The 3850 is EoS, but it can do SPAN if you can find one.

Comment: Yes, the 3850 switch models can do span, and you can do 10Gb if you also get the Network Module to add either 2, 4, or 8 10Gb SFP+ ports.  I think they may make a copper version of the network module that can go up to 10Gb but I’d have to look again to be sure.